# import .less file dynamically based on url

Tags: javascript

I have a `main.less` file where I have 2 less files and I want to load either of 2 based on url, for eg:

```
if url contain value=abc
@import 'test1.less';
if url contain value=xyz
@import 'test2.less';
```

I am using only Javascript, no JQuery.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Less is precompiled your suggesting running some code at Runtime to change precompiled code, this isnt possible unless your using it Client-side which in a Production enviroment will cause poor performance and potential reliability problems see http://lesscss.org/#client-side-usage

I suggest you use compiled CSS files with something like:

```
var = cssURL;
if(window.location.href =="www.someurl.com/home"){
   cssURL = "style1.css";
}else{
   cssURL = "style2.css";
}
var head = document.head, link = document.createElement('link')

link.type = 'text/css';
link.rel = 'stylesheet';
link.href = cssURL;

head.appendChild(link);
```

But if you are using less Client-side just change

```
link.rel = 'stylesheet/less';
```

Comment: Are you not precompiling your Less? If your using less files client-side in a production enviroment, that's just bad practise see http://lesscss.org/#client-side-usage

Answer (score 0):

```
Thanks for ur help....I found a rather much better way...add a class to body tag and make these entries in main less file
.class1 {
  @import 'test1.less';
}
.class2 {
  @import 'test2.less';}

and then identify ur url and change class name

document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].className="class2"

thats it
```